# Reloading/loading Grunt tasks after grunt-check-dependencies installs a Grunt task module

Tags: gruntjs

I have been trying to use grunt-check-dependencies to check for NPM module dependencies before running further Grunt tasks. The problem is that this doesn't help when one of the missing NPM dependencies is a Grunt task, e.g. grunt-contrib-concat.

Since Grunt apparently registers tasks before the 'checkDependencies' task is run, even though 'checkDependencies' will successfully install any missing Grunt task modules, it does this "too late" -- Grunt has already determined that the missing modules are missing, and the Grunt build run therefore fails.

One approach that will work is to always use a command line of e.g. "npm install; grunt ...", but I thought I would see if anyone has a completely 'Grunt-internal' solution.

Here's an example Grunt output that demonstrates the issue.

```
% rm -rf node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat ; grunt

>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-concat" not found. Is it installed?

Running "checkDependencies:this" (checkDependencies) task
>> grunt-contrib-concat: not installed!
Invoking npm install...
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-concat
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-concat
grunt-contrib-concat@0.3.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat
Warning: Task "concat:dev" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Here is the example gruntfile.js that caused the above output/error:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    'use strict';

    var config = {
        concat: {
            dev: {
                src: ['foo1.js', 'foo2.js'],
                dest: 'foo_concat.js'
            }
        },
        checkDependencies: {
            this: {
                options: {
                    npmInstall: true
                },
            },
        }
    };

    // trying to make sure all npm nodules listed in package.json are 
    // installed before other grunt tasks
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-check-dependencies');
    grunt.task.run('checkDependencies');

    // load grunt tasks
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // alternate approach to loading tasks; exhibits same problem
    // grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

    grunt.initConfig(config);

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat:dev']);
}
```